# How do I get a global menu in kde plasma 5?

Tags: kde, 15.10, plasma, kde5

I need a global menu in kde how can I get this.

Comment: Define global menu, you mean where the `file` `view` options go into the taskbar as aposed to the window ? KDE does not have that.

Comment: @markkirby it does indeed have some implementation of that: appmenu-qt. This indeed worked very well in KDE4, you could have the menu on the panel, as a mini-panel dropping from the top when needed, or popping out of a button in the application frame. Unfortunately with the move to qt5 that was omitted due to some incompatibilities. I'll try to find out more and post an answer.

Comment: @AF7 That's interesting, I did not know that, I don't use KDE on this PC so cant test this but I guess this is the QT5 version ? https://launchpad.net/appmenu-qt5

Comment: @markkirby yes, there is the QT5 version, but AFAIK it still does not add the required functionality. I'm writing a short answer now, I'll link the relevant bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In KDE4, the appmenu was nice and easy. See [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/how-to-enable-new-kde-410-appmenu-title.html).
In Plasma 5, however, this was discontinued. The reason is that `appmenu` made use of `dbusmenu` which has been deprecated by Canonical. Gnome now uses a new standard, `qmenumodel`.

Thus `appmenu` will need to be rewritten using `qmenumodel` to comply with the GNOME standard. You can see the relevant KDE bug report [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=341071) and KDE forum discussion [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=285&t=125058).

Maybe you should have researched a bit more: the above are the first pages that Google shows when searching "appmenu qt plasma5".

Comment: There was no need for that little extra at the end.  Ruins an otherwise solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

While it was true in the past this wasn't ported.  It is now working in the staging version of KDE, version 5.9.  You can read more about it here.

http://fasterland.net/activate-global-menu-kde-plasma-5-9.html
[image]

If you have KDE backports ppa or KDE Neon you should eventually get this version.

You can add those ppa's easily like this.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
```

If you want to add the source yourself check out the launchpad.
https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports